# socket timeout using check_http

Tags: nagios

I am trying to monitor version.json from nagios core 4.0.8 but it gives me a `socket timed out` error after 30 sec. I tried changing time but still it shows the same thing.

My `command.cfg` is:

```
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }
```

and my service is defined as

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       hostname
        service_description             https
        check_command                   check_http!-H hostname.com -u /versions.json -S -w 30 -c 40
        }
```

I tried changing the time with `-w` and `-c` but am still getting the socket timed out error.

If I need to make any changes please let me know.

Comment: From the nagios host, can you do 'telnet hostname.com 80' and get a connection? This error sounds like a connectivity issue rather than a nagios issue.

Comment: show us the output of `curl https://hostname.com/versions.json`

Comment: + To what Keith asked, what does the command line tell you?